# bootstrap daterangepicker javascript not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I'm trying to get a basic bootstrap date time picker working with cdn (content delivery network) but the external styles and scripts aren't being applied. This is probably something really small. I followed the instructions on the website [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

This is the code that will not work but should according to the examples:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    
    <!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
    <!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example works online now that I'm asking this question but it does not work locally. Can anyone let my know why this is and how can I get it to work locally on my own computer.

Comment: Have you verified that your javascript files are actually being loaded?

Comment: How are you loading your .html file? Via a local webserver, or directly into a browser? (you'll see your browser address bar say ".../folder/folder/index.html" or something similar). If this is the case, you'll want to add **http** to your ```src``` tags. Example: ```<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.... etc```. Can you open the 'developer console' and share what errors are being reported?

Comment: i believe your external links are wrong at some point. try to download and include them locally.

Comment: Yes Alex Johnson. I noticed that when I ran the file from localhost on my apache it worked. But when I ran the .html file from my desktop it didn't. I tried adding http:// and it worked. It wasn't accessing the resources properly before. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />




<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 300px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;

    <span name="datepick"></span>

    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
        var end = moment();

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

        }

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);

        cb(start, end);

    });
</script>
```